# how to pass value from fieldset select option to fieldset checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still new to Javascript and Jquery and am having a little trouble with this one.

I want to be able to pass a value from a fieldset (#a) with a select option to another fieldset (#b) with checkbox options.  For example, the fieldset #a has default options 1,2,3,4,5.   Fieldset #b can have many more options but must at least include the default from #a.

code snippet for fieldset #a:

```
      <fieldset id="a">
        <legend><span>Default Option</span></legend>  
        <div class="fieldset_wrapper">
          <select name="form_default">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <%=returnValueMap.get("defaultOptionSelect")%>

          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

code snippet for fieldset #b:

```
         <fieldset id="b">
         <legend><span>Option</span></legend>
            <div class="fieldset_wrapper">
              <div><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" class="checkAll"/>   All Options</div>

        <%=returnValueMap.get("optionSelect")%>

        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

Edit, here is something I tried but I think I'm obviously missing something. Again, i'm trying to learn this stuff

```
    $('#a option[name="form_default"]:selected').each(function(){   
                            $('#b input[type="checkbox"]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked',true);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: yes, i have tried a few things...  $('#at option[name="form_default"]:selected').each(function(){   
        $('#b input[type="checkbox"]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked',true);
  });

Comment: By "pass a value" did you mean when you select some option in the fieldset #a, check the corresponding checkbox in fieldset #b? What is the html produced by `<%=returnValueMap.get("optionSelect")%>`?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried in your question. It will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#a select').on('change', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  $('#b input[type="checkbox"][value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop("checked",true);  
})
```

Little explanations:

- Spy for changes and call the function on changes `$('#a select').on('change', function(e){`
- You don't really need that here, usually it's to remove the default behavior, for example it prevents changing page on links: `e.preventDefault()`
- We take the selected value in the select box: `$(this).val()`
- We select the corresponding checkbox using the Type, and the Value, like: `#b input[type="checkbox"][value="value selected in select box"]`
- Check the checkbox: `.prop("checked",true)`

may help you

**EDIT:** And if you want the default selected option go to `b` at the page load:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#b input[type="checkbox"][value="'+$('#a select').val()+'"]').prop("checked",true);
});
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit, I don't really understand what you want

Comment: The user selects a default option from the drop down select.  That value gets passed on to another fieldset that contains many checkboxes. For example, if the user selects drop down value "1" it gets passes to the other fieldset "b" so that "1" shows up as checked in fieldset "b."

Comment: That is what my code should do, but I infers some stuff you might need to change. I inferred that if `<option value="3">` then in fieldset b `<input type="checkbox" id="select-3" />`, but maybe your `returnValueMap` doesn't display `input` like this. If you want more help, you will need to provide the HTML code returned by your two `returnValueMap`

Comment: <fieldset id="a">
<legend>
<div class="fieldset_wrapper">
<select name="form_default">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option selected="" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>

Comment: <fieldset id="b">
<legend>
<div class="fieldset_wrapper">
<div>
<input id="select-all" class="checkAll" type="checkbox" name="select-all">
All Options
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="options">
<label>1</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="options">
<label>2</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="options">
<label>3</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="options">
<label>4</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="options">
<label>5</label>
</div>

Comment: thanks Tronixx....now I will take the rest of the day to figure out why it works.

Comment: I added some explanations if it can help you ;)